# Why does using margin left = 47% on hr have different action when using responsive desktop, mobile or tablet?

Tags: css

Why does using margin left = 47% on hr have different effect when responsive such as desktop, mobile or tablet? it does not stay in the same spot? thank in advance.

```css
hr {
  background-color: #33363b;
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 47% !important;
  margin-bottom: 2.5em;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section id="about-me">`
  <h3 class="section-title">About</h3>
  <hr size="8">
</section>
```

Comment: because it depend on the width of the parent which is changing. Pixed are used to have some always fixed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Values (The size of the margin as a percentage, relative to the width of the containing block.) --> an easy doc check and you have your answer